# I am rewriting a class component to a functional component in react-redux-firebase project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-redux-firebase

I am rebuilding this component.
https://github.com/ayush221b/MarioPlan-react-redux-firebase-app/blob/master/src/Components/projects/CreateProject.js

https://github.com/ayush221b/MarioPlan-react-redux-firebase-app/blob/master/src/store/actions/projectActions.js

however, I don't know how to rewrite mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps

The error says

> FirebaseError: Function addDoc() called with invalid data. Document fields must not be empty (found in field `` in document projects/5to35LFKROA5aKMXpjqy)

The project seems not be dispatched??

```
import  {Component ,useState}  from 'react'
import  {connect} from 'react-redux'
import  {createProject} from '../../store/actions/projectActions'
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'



const CreateProject = (props) => {

    const [state, setState] = useState({
        title: "",
        content: ""
      });

    const handleChange = event => {
        setState({ ...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
      };


    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(state);
        props.createProject(state);
        props.history.push('/');
      }

    const { auth } = props;
    return (
        <div className="container">
        <form className="white" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <h5 className="grey-text text-darken-3">Create a New Project</h5>
          <div className="input-field">
            <input type="text" id='title' onChange={handleChange} />
            <label htmlFor="title">Project Title</label>
          </div>
          <div className="input-field">
            <textarea id="content" className="materialize-textarea" onChange={handleChange}></textarea>
            <label htmlFor="content">Project Content</label>
          </div>
          <div className="input-field">
            <button className="btn pink lighten-1">Create</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    console.log("a"+dispatch);
    return {
        createProject: (project) => dispatch(createProject(project))
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
    return{
      auth: state.firebase.auth
    }
  }
  

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(CreateProject)
```

Answer (score 2):

in the functional component, you can use hooks like "useSelector" to get the store states

```
const firebase = useSelector(state => state.firebase)
```

and "useDispatch" to trigger an action

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()


<button  onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'GET_DATA' })} >Click me</button>
```

don't forget to import

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem: Missing `name` Property on Inputs

> FirebaseError: Function addDoc() called with invalid data. Document fields must not be empty (found in field `` in document projects/5to35LFKROA5aKMXpjqy)

This error doesn't have anything to do with `mapStateToProps`.  You are failing [this test](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/57c73a02ed10ef126a6b1c4d28ec607a0e0c8f42/packages/firestore/test/integration/api/validation.test.ts#L464) by passing a an object with an empty key.

```
{
  title: "Some Title", 
  content: "some content",
  '': "some value"
}
```

So where does that empty key come from?  Well you are setting values in the state with a dynamic key based on the `event.target.name`.

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
  setState({
    ...state, 
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value
  });
};
```

When you change the `input` or the `textarea`, what is `event.target.name`?  Take a look at your code.

```
<input type="text" id="title" onChange={handleChange} />
```

**There is no name property!**

You must either:
A) Add a `name` to each of the inputs that corresponds to the property which you want to update in the `state`.

```
<input type="text" id="title" name="title" onChange={handleChange} />
```

or B) Change your `setState` to use `event.target.id`, which is already set.

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
  setState({
    ...state,
    [event.target.id]: event.target.value
  });
};
```

I recommend B) as it looks like [that's what you were doing before](https://github.com/ayush221b/MarioPlan-react-redux-firebase-app/blob/27fd349965c22fd0af5755bc6853ca9240858d4e/src/Components/projects/CreateProject.js#L14).

#### Redux Hooks

Integrating with the redux hooks is very simple.  Easier than dealing with `connect`, in my opinion.

Access `auth` from a selector.

```
const auth = useSelector((state) => state.firebase.auth);
```

Call `useDispatch` add the top-level of your component to access `dispatch`.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
```

In your `handleSubmit`, call `dispatch` with the results of your action creator.

```
dispatch(createProject(state));
```

#### Complete Code

```
const CreateProject = (props) => {
  const auth = useSelector((state) => state.firebase.auth);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    title: "",
    content: ""
  });

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setState({ ...state, [event.target.id]: event.target.value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(state);
    dispatch(createProject(state));
    props.history.push("/");
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <form className="white" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h5 className="grey-text text-darken-3">Create a New Project</h5>
        <div className="input-field">
          <input type="text" id="title" onChange={handleChange} />
          <label htmlFor="title">Project Title</label>
        </div>
        <div className="input-field">
          <textarea
            id="content"
            className="materialize-textarea"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor="content">Project Content</label>
        </div>
        <div className="input-field">
          <button className="btn pink lighten-1">Create</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```